# How to load the PyPlot package in Julia-1.2.0-1

Tags: julia

I cannot load the PyPlot package using Julia 1.2.0-1 running on MacOS 10.15.1.

After starting Julia I type a ] to get to "Pkg".  I then type

> add PyPlot

and get the following messages:

> Updating registry at `~/.juliapro/JuliaPro_v1.2.01/registries/JuliaPro`
>    Updating git-repo `https://pkg.juliacomputing.com//registry/JuliaPro`
>   ERROR: GitError(Code:EMERGECONFLICT, Class:Checkout, 1332 conflicts prevent checkout)

followed by a lengthy stacktrace.  I have never seen this with previous Julia and MacOS versions; they just loaded the package.

> Deleting the registry and restarting Julia did the trick!  Thanks to all >who replied!

Comment: I would suggest restarting Julia Pro, doing a `build`, and then try adding it again.

Comment: I’m on the same versions as you and was able to add it successfully just now so I don’t think it’s anything too sinister.

Comment: You might have a corrupted registry, consider nuking `~/.juliapro/JuliaPro_v1.2.01/registries`?